# Postfix SPAM в заголовках for <info@ >

Tags: postfix, спам, spamassasin

Добрый день! нужна помощь в неравной борьбе со спамерами) 
вот мой конфиг postfix (та часть которая касается вопроса):

> ```
> smtpd_restriction_classes = verify_sender,
>                             rbl_cbl_abuseat_org,
>                             rbl_sbl_spamhaus_org,
>                             rbl_dul_ru, rbl_spamcop,
>                             white_client_ip,
>                             black_client_ip,
>                             block_dsl,
>                             helo_access,
>                             white_client,
>                             black_client,
>                             mx_access
>
> verify_sender        = reject_unverified_sender, permit 
> rbl_cbl_abuseat_org  = reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
> rbl_dul_ru           = reject_rbl_client dul.ru
> rbl_sbl_spamhaus_org = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org
> rbl_spamcop          = reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
> white_client_ip      = check_client_access pcre:/etc/postfix/config/white_client_ip
> black_client_ip      = check_client_access pcre:/etc/postfix/config/black_client_ip
> white_client         = check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/config/white_client
> black_client         = check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/config/black_client
> block_dsl            = regexp:/etc/postfix/config/block_dsl
> helo_access          = check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/config/helo_checks
> mx_access            = check_sender_mx_access cidr:/etc/postfix/config/mx_access
>
> smtpd_client_restrictions = white_client_ip,
>                             black_client_ip,
>                             white_client,
>                             black_client,
>                             helo_access,
>                             block_dsl,
>                             rbl_dul_ru,
>                             rbl_sbl_spamhaus_org,
>                             rbl_spamcop,
>                             rbl_cbl_abuseat_org,
>                             permit_mynetworks,
>                             permit_sasl_authenticated,
>                             reject_unauth_destination,
>                             reject_unauth_pipelining,
>                             reject_unknown_address,
>                             reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
>                             reject_unknown_sender_domain
> smtpd_sender_restrictions = white_client,
>                             white_client_ip,
>                             black_client_ip,
>                             reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
>                             reject_unknown_sender_domain,
>                             reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
>                             reject_non_fqdn_sender,
>                             permit_sasl_authenticated,
>                             permit_mynetworks,
>                             mx_access,
>                             reject_unlisted_sender,
>                             reject_unauth_destination
> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = verify_sender,
>                                white_client,
>                                helo_access,
>                                reject_non_fqdn_sender,
>                                reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
>                                reject_unknown_sender_domain,
>                                reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
>                                reject_unauth_pipelining,
>                                permit_sasl_authenticated,
>                                permit_mynetworks,
>                                reject_unlisted_recipient,
>                                reject_unknown_address,
>                                reject_unauth_destination,
>                                reject_multi_recipient_bounce, 
>                                check_policy_service inet:localhost:10023
>
> smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining,
>                           reject_multi_recipient_bounce,
>                           permit
> smtp_skip_5xx_greeting = no
> smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
> smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
> ```

Прописаны правильно MX, есть DKIM, SPF записи (DMARC нету), включен грейлистинг. Так вот, периодически валится спам на info@ и contact@ ящики его отличительная черта что и отправитель и получатель никак не связаны с почтовым доменом но в заголовках есть отношение к почтовому домену:

> ```
> Received: from mail.spammers.net (mail.spammers.net [ip-address])
>         by my-post.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 5B56A00000
>         for <info@domain.com>; Sun,  2 Jul 2017 20:42:10 +0000 (CEST)
> Message-ID: <it581458.43231@mail.spammers.net>
> Reply-To: "Original SPAM" <it@spammers.net>
> From: "Original SPAM" <it@spammers.net>
> To: <g.meriseeg@postmotmydomain.gg>
> Subject: Subj spammers
> Date: Sun, 02 Jul 2017 20:14:39 +0000
> ```

Как фильтровать такие письма? есть spamassasin но даже после обучения его на примере 10-ов писем подобных, он пропускает такие письма.

Comment: Что значит "получатель не связан с почтовым доменом" это же именно ваш info судя по заголовку

Comment: в to и rcpt указан не мой домен

Comment: Понял, т.е. попадание ящика в заголовк Received объясняеется использованием спамерами BCC и фильтровать такие письма сложно так как они соответствуют стандартам, получается так? на все ящики для сервисов будет постоянно щемится пара-тройка спама

Comment: И кстати, что у вас RBL в постфиксе делает ? только не говорите что он письмо вообще отвергает из за попадания в какой нибудь спамхауз. Уже были случаи что спамхауз писал в списке целых крупных провайдеров из за одного спамера в их сети. RBL можно использовать опять же только как дополнительную меру в спамассасине, т.е. добавлять некий балл. обычно больше 2.0 я за попадание в RBL письму не даю (при пороге спама в 5.0)

Comment: Хорошо учту, содержимое письма base64. Спасибо за ответ @Mike все понял.

Comment: У меня кстати есть модуль для спамассассин который номера телефонов из писем выделяет (справляется практически со всеми способами кодирования). но он дико заточен на мою систему, например телефоны хранит в Oracle. я подумываю его сделать общедоступным, более универсальным, но пока не понимаю на сколько он нужен. просто даже после переделки он будет не самым простым в установке, как минимум для качественного анализа ему нужны на машине куча утилит по конвертации/распознаванию изображений и выделению текстов из pdf и doc файлов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные заголовки у легального письма могут быть в случае, если ваш адрес `info@domain.com` был указан в BCC (скрытая копия) письма. С учетом того, что люди редко используют BCC можно на свой стах и риск добавить в spamassasin следующее правило:

```
header __MY_DOAIN_CC   cc =~ /mydomain\.com/
header __MY_DOMAIN_TO  to =~ /mydomain\.com/
meta   FOREIGN_TO    (! __MY_DOAIN_CC && ! __MY_DOMAIN_TO)
score  FOREIGN_TO 0.5
```

В нем мы проверяем есть ли упоминание нашего почтового домена в заголовках `to` и `cc` письма. И в случае, если нашего домена не оказалось ни в получателе ни в копии добавляем письму 0.5 к спам-рейтингу. Больше 0.5 я бы давать не рискнул, все таки нормальные письма с такими заголовками теоретически возможны.

**Внимание**: после изменения любых конфигов *всегда* проверяйте их корректность с помощью `spamassassin --lint`

Остальные заголовки в письме к сожалению сформированы по всем стандартам, даже Message-ID с того же домена, что и From, зацепиться больше не за что.